# Magento 2 : Display Loader While Ajax call on Column row action?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Grid xml column:

```
<column name='actions' class='My\Test\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Feeds\AdvancedActions'> 
    <argument name='data' xsi:type='array'> 
        <item name='config' xsi:type='array'>
            <item name='component' xsi:type='string'>My_Test/js/grid/columns/actions</item> 
            <item name='dataType' xsi:type='string'>text</item> 
            <item name='label' xsi:type='string' translate='true'>Actions</item> 
            <item name='sortOrder' xsi:type='number'>90</item> 
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Actions.js

```
define(
    [
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ], function ($, _, utils, registry, Column, confirm) {
        'use strict';
    return Column.extend(
        {

            /**
             * Applies specified action.
             *
             * @param   {String} actionIndex - Actions' identifier.
             * @param   {Number} rowIndex - Index of a row.
             * @returns {ActionsColumn} Chainable.
             */
            applyAction: function (actionIndex, rowIndex) {
                var action = this.getAction(rowIndex, actionIndex),
                callback = this._getCallback(action);

                if (action.confirm) {
                    this._confirm(action, callback);
                } else if (action.popup) {
                    this._popup(action, callback);
                } else {
                    callback();
                }

                return this;
            },


           _popup: function (action, callback) {
                var popupData = action.popup;
                var dataType = popupData.type;

                //Start loader
                var body = $('body').loader();
                body.loader('show');

                if (popupData.file !== undefined && popupData.file !== '') {
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: popupData.file,
                            async: false,
                            dataType: "text",
                            type: 'GET',
                            showLoader: true, //use for display loader
                            success: function (data) {
                                popupData.message = data;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                //Stop loader
                body.loader('hide');
            },
});
```

Used `showLoader: true` and `var body = $('body').loader(); body.loader('show');` but unable to start loader while ajax request.

Need an  alternative to start loader during ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case, I need to load the `'jquery/ui'` dependency.

```
define(
    [
    'jquery',
    ...
    'jquery/ui'
```

Comment: Try to clear cache, and put `jquery/ui` as the last dependency.

Comment: Tried but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below code which might help.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
], function ($,fullScreenLoader
) {
    //Start Loader
    fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
    //Your AJax COde here

    //Stop Loader
    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `loader` dependency to the end:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    ...
    'loader'
]
```

`showLoader: true` and 
`var body = $('body'); body.loader('hide');` will start working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('body').trigger('processStart')` & `$('body').trigger('processStop')`

Answer (score 0):

Because you using async: false try to refactor you code to change logic async: true ajax call

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).